# cakephp: How can i add dropdownlist in default.ctp?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

In default.ctp I want to add two dropdownlists.
One is list of year from 2010 to 2020 and the another one is a list of month from January to December.

How can i do this ?

Do i have to create form for this ? like

```
echo $this->Form->create...
echo $this->Form->end..
```

Or can i just add two dropdownlists and a search button ?

The if i click the "Search" button it will go for posts/archive action and display those posts with that "year-month" in "created" column of posts table.

Can anyone post sample code for this?

This is what i tried so far :
            $listyear = array();

```
        for($i=2010;$i<=2020;$i++){
            array_push($listyear,$i);
        }


        $track=array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

        $months=array(1=>'January',
                      2=>'February',
                      3=>'March',
                      4=>'April',

                      5=>'May',
                      6=>'June',
                      7=>'July',
                      8=>'August',

                      9=>'September',
                      10=>'October',
                      11=>'November',
                      12=>'December');                                                  

        echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('url' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' =>'listarchive')));
        echo $this->Form->input('Select year',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$listyear) );           
        echo $this->Form->input('Select month',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$months) );
        echo $this->Form->end('Search');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a form (or use JavaScript, but a normal HTML form is easier and more reliable). You can use `Form::year()` to create a dropdown list for a year and `Form::month()` for months: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1416/year and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1417/month.

If you have problems with creating the form, it'd be better if you posted what you have tried and asked specific questions. Forms are covered quite extensively in the Cookbook (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1383/Form).

EDIT after seeing code: You could just do something like this and let Cake do the work:

```
echo $form->create( 'Post', array( /* whatever you need */ ) );
echo $form->year( 'year', 2010, 2020 );
echo $form->month( 'month' );
echo $form->end( 'Search' );
```

Comment: Well, if it works it's correct ;) It does look like you're doing a lot of stuff Cake could do automatically. See edited answer.

Comment: In posts table there is no column named "year" or "month" , is that a problem ? I will have to get the value data['Post']['year'] and data['Post']['month'] then compare the 'created' column of posts table, that's all

Comment: That's not a problem. You use whatever logic you need in the controller.